# Why is HTTP/2 slower for me in FireFox?

Tags: http, firefox, http2

There's a very interesting HTTP/2 demo that Akamai have on their site:

https://http2.akamai.com/demo

HTTP/2 (the future of HTTP) allows for concurrently downloaded assets over a single TCP connection reducing the need for spritesheets and concatenation... As I understand it, it should always be quicker on sites with lots of requests (like in the demo).

When I try the demo in Chrome or Safari it is indeed much faster, but when I've tested it in FireFox it's consistently **SLOWER**. Same computer, same connection.

Why is this?

[image]

HTTP/2 is apparently [supported by all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=http2), including FireFox, so it should work fine, but in this real world demonstration it is slower 80% of the time. (In Chrome and Safari it's faster 100% of the time.)

I tried again on the following Monday after ensuring I'd cleared all my caches:

[image]

My OS: El Capitan Version 10.11.3 (15D21) with FireFox Version 44.0.2

**UPDATE (APR 2016)**

Now running Firefox 45.0.1:

[image]

Still slower!

Comment: Did you clear your cache before checking that page?

Comment: @Evert Of course. The worst scores I got where actually when I ran the page for the very first time... but I didn't take a screenshot.

Comment: Well not sure about you but I'm getting lower "Load time" for HTTP/2 than 1 in my Firefox Nightly

Comment: For me it's slower about 80% of the time. Strange.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to have a pretty small latency and a very fast network.

My typical results for HTTP/1.1 are latency=40ms, load_time=3.5s, and HTTP/2 is consistently 3 times faster.

With a network such as yours, other effects may come into play.

In my experience one of the most important is the cipher that is actually negotiated.

HTTP/2 mandates the use of very strong ciphers, while HTTP/1.1 (over TLS) allows for far weaker, and therefore faster, ciphers.

In order to compare apples to apples, you would need to make sure that the same cipher is used. For me, for this Akamai demo, the same cipher was used.

The other thing that may be important is that the HTTP/1.1 sources are downloaded from `http1.akamai.com`, while for HTTP/2 they are downloaded from `http2.akamai.com`. For me they resolve to different addresses.

One should also analyze how precise is the time reported in the demo :)

The definitive answer can only come from a network trace with tools like Wireshark.

For networks worse than yours, probably the majority, HTTP/2 is typically a clear winner due to HTTP/2 optimizations related to latency (in particular, multiplexing).

Comment: Good answer, although you seem to be implying that 'https has weak security. While, as a rough rule of thumb, stronger ciphers do require more processing, this is not universally true. Nor does more processing directly imply poorer performance(although capacity can be a consideration). 'https gives the *option* of using weaker ciphers, which http/2 won't allow.

Comment: How can it be a network issue when the same connection, same computer, gives me better results in different browsers? Thanks.

Comment: That is an interesting question, that cannot be answered without a network trace and a detailed analysis of what is actually being measured by that page. Out of curiosity, is HTTP/2 bettern than HTTP/1.1 if you use [`nghttp2`](https://nghttp2.org/) rather than a browser ?

Answer (score 2):

Latency matters more than absolute load time if you're mixing small and big resources. E.g. if you're loading a very large image but also a small stylesheets then HTTP2's multiplexing over a single connection that can have the stylesheets finish while the image is still loading. The page can be rendered with the final styles and - assuming that the image is progressive - will also display a low-res version of the image.

In other words, the tail end of a load might be much less important if it's caused by a few big resources.

That said, the demo page actually loads http2 faster for me on FF nightly most of the time, although there is some variance. You might need better measurements.